# How to get android context from a reference of interface?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-context

I have an activity which instantiate a class with an interface. How I can get the android context within MyClass with only the reference to the interface?

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onChange() {

    }
}


public interface MyInterface {
    void onChange();
}

public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
       // how to get context from myInterface ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(MyInterface myInterface) {
    // Get Context
    Context context = null;
    if (myInterface instanceOf Context)
        context = (Context)myInterface;
    }
}
```

If your `Activity` (which `extends Context`) is implementing `MyInterface` and you pass that to `MyClass`, you just need to cast it to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

The context is only available in `Activity` classes or global `Context`, if you have to use the context, change your code:

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final MyClass myClass = new MyClass(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChange() {

        }
    }


    public interface MyInterface {
        void onChange();
    }

    public class MyClass {
        public MyClass(TestActivity activity) {
        //now, you can use the context of your activity or do a cast 
        // to your interface
       MyInterface interface = (MyInterface) activity;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I know I could always change the constructor, but the hard point is that I don't have the control of `MyClass` constructor (it extends from a library, and it requires me to use this constructor). Worse part is I don't have control of the `TestActivity` either. The only part I could change is what's inside the `MyClass` constructor. Should I just use a cast to cast `MyInterface` to context, i.e.: `(Context) myInterface`

Answer (score 0):

I think you approached it a bit wrong, but I might miss understood your design concept what you want to achieve.

Create your Interface in the Class where you want to obtain the Context from and the use implement like you did in your activity.

```
YourContextClass() {
 private MyInterface interface;

 onCreate() {
  interface.onChange(this);
 }

 public interface MyInterface() {
  void onChange(Context context);
 }
}
```

Then in your Activity class implement MyInterface, and inside the method, you can obtain the Context.

```
YourActivity implements MyInterface {
 private Context context;
 ...

  void onChange(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
 }

}
```

But this is only necessary if you really need the context from Interface... otherwise, in you Activity, I see you are extending`Activity`, which gives you access to the Context with `getContext();`